# inversely proportional utility functions

Tags: microeconomics, utility

If I have two products $x$ and $y$ and two users $A$ and $B$ whose utility functions for those products $u$ and $w$ are inversely proportional, would it be ok to express this relationship as: $u(x,y) = w^{-1}(x,y)$? Thanks.

Comment: Two variables $p,q$ are **inversely proportional** if $pq=K$ where $K$ is a constant. So if $u$ and $w$ are inversely proportional if for any pair of products $(x,y)$, $$u(x,y)=\frac{K}{w(x,y)}$$ for some fixed $K$.

Comment: This is somewhat a strange relationship. It means that $A$ dislikes consuming the goods that $B$ likes. Is it what you have in mind? Otherwise, could you provide a little more context?

Comment: @HerrK could you please explain me why you need $pq$ to define $K$? I don't know much about utility functions, but I am trying to focus on only two products $xy$. Or in your example $K$ is a constant of $xy$?

Comment: @Oliv yes, that's exactly the kind of relationship I am looking to establish. For example if I have two products that may have different colours $A$ dislikes exactly what $B$ likes and vice versa. Does $w^{-1}$ implies that?

Comment: @vabm: You can think of $p,q$ in my case as two utility numbers; for instance $u(x,y)=p$ and $w(x,y)=q$. If $p$ and $q$ are inversely proportional, then $p=K/q$, for some $K$. In your case, $K=1$, but it could take other values too.

Comment: @vabm: I suppose the expression you wrote is almost correct, except perhaps for a notational issue. I would write $u(x,y)=[w(x,y)]^{-1}$, because $w^{-1}(x,y)$ is usually used to denote the **pre-image** of $w(x,y)$.

Comment: @vabm: in that case, you can simply posit $u(x,y)=-w(x,y)$ to guarantee that, $u(x,y)>u(x',y')$,implies $w(x,y)<w(x',y')$. Writing $u(x,y)=\frac{1}{w(x,y)}$ is ok as well if the utility functions take positive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer...

I suppose the expression you wrote is *almost* correct, except perhaps for a notational issue. I would write $u(x,y)=[w(x,y)]^{-1}$, because $w^{-1}(x,y)$ is usually used to denote the **pre-image** of $w(x,y)$.

More generally, inverse proportionality between $u$ and $w$ is defined up to a multiplicative constant $K$; that is, $u(x,y)\cdot w(x,y)=K$ for some $K\in\mathbb R$. In the above case, you implicitly assumed $K=1$. So generally, you'd have 
$$
u(x,y)=K[w(x,y)]^{-1}=\frac{K}{w(x,y)}.
$$